# cifs, smb - Can't mount (permission denied) or navigate shared folder

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, cifs

I've recently bumped into this problem. I usually navigate through a local network shared folder from a Linux machine via smb (i.e. from file manger using smb: ).
Now whenever I try to access the shortcut or typing credential again I keep getting the dialog window asking for user, domain and password.

So I tried mounting the location manually using cisf-utils doing:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //fileshare1/docs1/user/My\ Documents/shared/Francesco/ /home/frank/used_shared/ -o username=my_user,password=my_pass,domain=my_domain,gid=1000,uid=1000
```

I get `mount error(13): Permission denied`.

I'm definitely sure my user has permission on that folder cause I can access it from a windows machine.

Also if I try to mount my personal folder on that location through:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //fileshare1/docs5/francesco.azzarello/ /home/frank/mnt_folder -o username=my_user,password=my_pass,domain=my_domain,gid=1000,uid=1000
```

I can access it with no problem.

For reference I'm using 4.2.0-36-generic kernel and my mount.cifs version is 6.4

Any idea on how to make one of both methods work?

---

**Update** Rgarding ponsfrilus answer

number 1: verbose option returns:

```
_mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,unc=\\fileshare1\docs1,uid=1000,gid=1000,user=my_user,,domain=my_domain,prefixpath=user/My Documents/shared/Francesco/,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)_
```

Number 2 is basically the same thing:

```
_ mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,unc=\\fileshare1\docs1,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,user=my_user,,domain=my_domain,prefixpath=user/My Documents/shared/Francesco/,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)_
```

And nothing changed with vers=2.1:

```
_mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,unc=\\fileshare1\docs1,vers=2.1,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,user=my_user,,domain=my_domain,prefixpath=user/My Documents/shared/Francesco/,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)_
```

As for number 4 I can mount docs1 no problem but I can navigate tho get to the shared folder in user.

Comment: Try ponsfrilus' tip #3 with `vers=3.0`, maybe also `vers=2.0` or `vers=1.0`. If this doesn't work, maybe you can allow the server a broader range of smb versions to connect. I had this issue myself because smb3 was set on the server as required. I couldn't connect with linux until the server lowered the required samba version to 2. What OS does the server run?

Comment: I tried all of them. I still get "permission denied" with 3.0, 2.1 and 2.0. While I get "unknown error" with 1.0. 
I don't know how to check the windows server version as user since I don't have direct access to it.

Comment: Can't help you on that, sorry. I had control over the server and my problem went away after relaxing the allowed SMB versions.
You can connect to your own share - linux misconfiguration unlikely;
you can connect via windows to share - server misconfiguration unlikely. This calls for a real samba guru.

Answer (score 21):

I'm pretty sure I ran into this exact same problem today on Ubuntu 16.10 I tried all the suggestions in this thread several times, I could mount the exact same share using Windows Server 2016 and I could browse it using smbclient (`smbclient -U brainstrust //WINBOX01/shared`).  I even tried an external credentials file.

I ended up stumbling on a fix - although I'd created a local user for the share on the Windows box, it was also joined to a domain.  Basically setting the domain to be the local machine `-o domain=WINBOX01` fixed my problem instantly, so leaving a comment here in the hope that its useful to someone out there.

The complete minimal command I used was:

```
sudo mount.cifs -v //WINBOX01/shared /home/geoff/winbox01  --verbose -o user=brainstrust,password=topsecret,domain=WINBOX01
```

Comment: Thanks for leaving this comment here, it helped me out.

Comment: Helped me too.  Appears that mount -t cifs suffers from the same problem

Comment: This is what turned out to be my problem. I already had a `~/.smbcredentials` file. I'm horrified to find out my local NAS has let me mount the share with a bad password for a very long time.

Comment: Oddly enough, we needed to specify the domain NetBIOS name, not the fileserver's hostname. Nevertheless, it does work now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12):

I think you have the wrong security type for the server , error 13 means the server isn't letting you in.

You will need to select the right security mode in your mount command add a sec option via -o as follows [[reference]](https://www.samba.org/%7Eab/output/htmldocs/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html):

```
sec=
   Security mode. Allowed values are:
   ·   none - attempt to connection as a null user (no name)
   ·   krb5 - Use Kerberos version 5 authentication
   ·   krb5i - Use Kerberos authentication and forcibly enable packet 
       signing
   ·   ntlm - Use NTLM password hashing
   ·   ntlmi - Use NTLM password hashing and force packet signing
   ·   ntlmv2 - Use NTLMv2 password hashing
   ·   ntlmv2i - Use NTLMv2 password hashing and force packet signing
   ·   ntlmssp - Use NTLMv2 password hashing encapsulated in Raw NTLMSSP message
   ·   ntlmsspi - Use NTLMv2 password hashing encapsulated in Raw NTLMSSP message, and force packet signing
```

Comment: I tried all of them and I receive "permission denied" or "unknown error" depending on the sec type

Comment: given all the recent security issues with SMB I would advice only using it where a lot of additional security measures are in place , such as very up to date virus checking.

Comment: Try using sec=ntlmssp, and make sure your samba server config encrypts the password.

Comment: Saved my day. Actually what I did was just remove the sec=ntlm and then it worked.

Comment: You really should move away from SMB these days, it's a near constant source of attacks and privelege escalation.

Comment: Note that exclusion of the `sec` parameter is not the same as some default `none` or `ntlm` value.

Comment: adding sec=ntlm was the final step to get a centos 7 linux box to connect to an old rohde and schwarz SMU200A generator stil running windows xp. Another centos 7 box did not need this flag. weird.

Answer (score 9):

1. Try to add the "-v" option to get verbose output:

   ```
   sudo mount -v -t cifs //fileshare1/docs1/user/My\ 
      Documents/shared/Francesco/ /home/frank/mnt_folder -o \
      username=my_user,password=my_pass,domain=my_domain,gid=1000,uid=1000
   ```
2. Test with these options to the mount command

   **iocharset=utf8,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777**:

   ```
   sudo mount -v -t cifs //fileshare1/docs1/user/My\ 
      Documents/shared/Francesco/ /home/frank/mnt_folder -o 
      username=my_user,password=my_pass,domain=my_domain,\
      iocharset=utf8,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
   ```
3. Test specifying the SMB version option (vers=2.1), see [the samba wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS). From the mount.cifs man page:

   > vers=
   >              SMB protocol version. Allowed values are:
   >
   > - 1.0 - The classic CIFS/SMBv1 protocol. This is the default.
   > - 2.0 - The SMBv2.002 protocol. This was initially introduced in Windows Vista Service Pack 1, and
   >                Windows Server 2008. Note that the initial release version of Windows Vista spoke a slightly
   >                different dialect (2.000) that is not supported.
   > - 2.1 - The SMBv2.1 protocol that was introduced in Microsoft Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008R2.
   > - 3.0 - The SMBv3.0 protocol that was introduced in Microsoft Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.
4. Finally, try to mount only the first share :

   ```
   sudo mount -v -t cifs //fileshare1/docs1/ /home/frank/mnt_folder \
      -o username=my_user,password=my_pass,domain=my_domain,\
      iocharset=utf8,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
   ```

Any verbose output you can share might help.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I Didn't find any better way to replay other than update the question. you can find the outputs of those commands in the update

Comment: @Frankmtl can you compare the folders rights inside docs1 and docs5 fileshare1 ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  If you mean the folder permissions after i mount them, they both have drwxr-xr-x

Comment: To access a Windows 2012 server share (smb2),  you must add  `,vers=2.1`      after uid=1000 (aka end of line) . I installed also "cifs-utils" package.

Comment: I'm still getting the permission denied error, even when settings the file_mode/dir_mode variables. Here's what my line looks like:

```
//192.168.50.230/entire-library  /mnt/shares/nsfw cifs credentials=/home/raleigh/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

And if I run the mount command with the verbose flag, I get this:

/                        : ignored
/boot/efi                : already mounted
none                     : ignored
mount.cifs: permission denied

Answer (score 3):

For this problem when using cifs higher than 6.0:
new version of cifs use the domain variable instead, so creadentials file look like:

```
username=<your username>
password=<your password>
domain=<your domain>
```

Comment: The solution for me was indeed no spaces before and after `=`.

Comment: Thanks mate.  Solved my problem.  Was missing domain=.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the option `sec=ntlm` to the mount command  resolved my issue.

eg:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=administrator,password=123456,sec=ntlm //ip/eeshare /mnt/eeshare/
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me add my foobar for this situation:

I was providing a default smb_creds file to be used in the mount string:

`ro,credentials=/home/ubuntu/.smb_creds,uid=ubuntu,gid=ubuntu`

But unfortunately the ansible template file I was using was using CRLF newlines from my windows machine. I had to change the newlines back to linux LF and was able to mount the share.

Same observation as others had: On the first machine I had manually mounted the share to test it via shell commands, then I used the `fstab` entry above with the *wrong* line endings in the creds file, but this machine did not complain a bit and used some cached version of the credentials.

This is a WTF. o_0

I only stumbled upon this when I was provisioning another machine with similar smb config only to find out, that I got permission denied.

Hope this is another solution for somebody